# Unable to filter out duplicate lines when trying to find sum

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following query that is returning duplicate lines for the Total FG / Total RM usage columns.
It should be summing that title for the item code, and not showing separate lines for the item:

Query:

```
SELECT
     distinct(convert(varchar(100),T3.itemcode,101)) as 'Item Code',   
    T2.Quantity  as 'Total RM Usage', 
    '0' 'Total FG Usage', 
    --convert(varchar(100),T3.itemcode,101) as 'Item Code',
    --dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, T1.DocDate),0) as 'Month Start Date' , 
    convert(Varchar(10),T4.ItmsGrpNam,101) as 'Item Group', 
    convert(Varchar(10),T3.U_BusinessUnit, 101) as 'Business Unit',
     convert(varchar(100), T5.onhand, 101) as 'On Hand Qty',
    convert(varchar(100), T5.AvgPrice, 101) as 'Price',
    Convert(varchar(100), (T5.Onhand)*(T5.Avgprice), 101) as 'On Hand 
  Cost',
  convert(varchar(100), (T5.whscode), 101) as 'Whse',
  T1.docdate as 'Doc Date'
   from OIGE T1   
  Inner join IGE1 T2 on T1.Docentry = T2.DocEntry
  Inner Join OITM T3 on T2.Itemcode = T3.ItemCode
  left join OITB T4 on T3.ItmsGrpCod = T4.ItmsGrpCod
  left join OITW T5 on T3.itemcode = T5.ItemCode --and T2.WhsCode = 
  T5.WhsCode
  Where T3.ItmsGrpCod in ('109', 
  '110','111','112','113','114','115','116','117','118','119','120') and 
  T1.Canceled <> 'Y' and T3.ItemCode <> 'Avatax' and T5.onhand <> '0' --- 
  and T3.Itemcode = $[$5.0.0] 
  Group By T4.ItmsGrpNam,dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, T1.DocDate),0), 
  T3.U_BusinessUnit, T5.onhand, T5.AvgPrice, T3.itemcode, T5.whscode, 
  T2.Quantity, T1.docdate 

  UNION ALL
  SELECT
   distinct(convert(varchar(100),T3.itemcode,101)) as 'Item Code',  
   '0' 'Total RM Usage', 
   T2.Quantity  'Total FG Usage',
  --dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, T1.DocDate),0) as 'Month Start Date', 
  convert(Varchar(10),T4.ItmsGrpNam,101), 
  convert(Varchar(10),T3.U_BusinessUnit, 101),
  convert(varchar(100), T5.onhand, 101),
  convert(varchar(100), T5.AvgPrice, 101),
  Convert(varchar(100), (T5.Onhand)*(T5.Avgprice), 101),
  convert(varchar(100), (T5.whscode), 101) as 'Whse',
  T1.docdate as 'Doc Date'
  from ODLN T1  
  Inner join DLN1 T2 on T1.docEntry = T2.DocEntry
  left Join OITM T3 on T2.Itemcode = T3.ItemCode
  left join OITB T4 on T3.ItmsGrpCod = T4.ItmsGrpCod
   left join OITW T5 on T3.itemcode = T5.ItemCode --and T2.WhsCode = 
  T5.WhsCode
  Where T3.ItmsGrpCod in ('100', 
  '101','102','104','105','106','107','108') and T1.Canceled <> 'Y' and 
  T3.ItemCode <> 'Avatax' and T5.onhand <> '0' --T2.Itemcode = 
 $[OITM.ItemCode] and 
Group By T4.ItmsGrpNam, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, T1.DocDate),0),T3.U_BusinessUnit, T5.onhand, T5.AvgPrice, t3.itemcode, T5.whscode, 
T2.Quantity, T1.docdate
```

Example of that I'm seeing:

```
Item Code   Total RM Usage  Total FG Usage  Item Group  Business Unit   On Hand Qty Price   On Hand Cost    Whse
0000000 0.019048    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 0.130000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 0.135000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 0.231000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 0.270000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 0.350000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 0.450000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 0.490000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 1.120000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 1.170000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2.000000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2.450000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2.680000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 6.375000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 6.860000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 7.840000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 7.900000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 8.380000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 9.310000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 9.340000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 10.350000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 11.680000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 12.130000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 12.940000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 14.000000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 14.800000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 14.974000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 15.600000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 18.000000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 21.000000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 21.500000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 21.600000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 21.720000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 22.159620   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 22.323548   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 31.050000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 32.500000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 32.600000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 39.000000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 42.000000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 52.480400   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 54.000000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 56.000000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 62.500000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 68.000000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 83.097000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 83.300000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 84.000000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 85.000000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 85.500000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 87.771000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 93.587616   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 94.000000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 94.070000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 94.250000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 94.950000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 95.000000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 95.020000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 95.040000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 95.491750   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 96.823468   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 97.025319   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 97.544110   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 98.308044   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 98.798330   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 99.000000   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 99.106184   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 99.185998   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 99.767500   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 99.824510   0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 100.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 100.303394  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 100.582743  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 108.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 108.830000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 108.970000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 110.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 115.517500  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 118.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 126.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 137.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 142.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 144.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 158.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 188.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 200.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 208.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 210.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 220.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 234.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 236.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 267.033600  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 270.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 275.640000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 278.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 308.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 311.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 315.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 328.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 420.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 481.780000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 525.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 554.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 591.675000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 595.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 600.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 608.391000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 609.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 610.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 614.691000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 615.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 617.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 617.217292  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 617.400000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 619.500000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 620.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 629.700000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 632.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 636.279000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 640.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 651.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 680.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 705.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 708.540000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 727.200000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 730.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 765.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 793.200000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 931.527100  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 995.000000  0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 1185.000000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 1575.724010 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 1767.919372 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 1924.070112 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 1926.181968 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 1979.000000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 1980.000000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 1980.190000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 1980.560000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 1981.000000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 1985.000000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 1988.000000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 1989.933500 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 1990.000000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 1999.000000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 1999.990000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2008.000000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2010.000000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2018.000000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2020.000000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2021.891238 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2024.000000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2032.702220 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2048.621688 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2051.122500 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2058.838660 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2066.917196 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2080.223020 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2081.000000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2083.000000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2090.202388 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2096.023686 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2109.257500 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2145.618090 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 2165.987478 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 6190.000000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 6506.900000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 6590.000000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 7514.400000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 7515.000000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 7550.000000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 8196.400000 0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 12255.000000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
0000000 12400.000000    0.000000    RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.099300   0.010000    1388.43099300000    MESA
```

What I want to see
000000  172964.5207 0   RM-Blowing  Insulation  138843.0993 0.01    1388.430993 MESA

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible sample case. You want answers, right?

Comment: I think you don't want all those `group by` columns. Perhaps you were thinking of `order by`?

Comment: Also based on extra parens, somebody appears to think that `distinct` operates as something like a function, which is not the case. I think you need to explain better what this is supposed to be accomplishing. (Assuming my first suggestion isn't right.)

Comment: At the moment you are just appending a resultset to another one. 
If you want summarized data you need to apply grouping on the union:ed data